# Connect Arduino to Blynk with ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, blynk

so I got my Arduino Uno today. For a porject I want to be able to control some relays on my Arduino via Wifi (via Blynk app). For this I want to use the ESP8266-01 as a Wifi shield.

I used this tutorial: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/nolan-mathews/connect-to-blynk-using-esp8266-as-arduino-uno-wifi-shield-m1-46a453

Only difference is I'm using Win10. Here is what I got:

- Arduino Uno R3
- Arduino IDE 1.8.1
- included all Blynk/ESP libraries and installed ESP8266 as board (generic)
- uploaded empty sketch to the Arduino
- Connections to Between Arduino/ESP as follows . http://www.teomaragakis.com/hardware/electronics/how-to-connect-an-esp8266-to-an-arduino-uno/ (I know about to 3.3V to 5V issue but seems to work so far)

Okay, first problem is that I couldnt flash the Firmware of the ESP (got it from Sunfounder) as said in the Tutorial. Downloaded the latest firmware and flashed it with ESP8266Flasher.

Other Problem that is when I try to compile the code from the first tutorial, I always get error :

```
C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Blynk\examples\Boards_WiFi\ESP8266_Shield\ESP8266_Shield.ino:5:21: fatal error: ESP8266.h: No such file or directory
```

As said I have installed all libraries. Cant really think of things to do anymore. Any help would be much appreciated. Best regards from Berlin, Chris.
To close the code I try to upload to the board (both Arduino Board or generic ESP8266 does not work)

```
//#define BLYNK_DEBUG
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial  // Comment this out to disable prints and    save space
#include <ESP8266.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleShieldEsp8266.h>
// Set ESP8266 Serial object
#define EspSerial Serial
ESP8266 wifi(EspSerial);
// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "???";
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(115200);  // Set console baud rate
 delay(10);
 EspSerial.begin(115200);  // Set ESP8266 baud rate
 delay(10);
 Blynk.begin(auth, wifi, "???",
"???");
}
void loop()
{
 Blynk.run();
}
```

The ??? I switched for my token and data ofc.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this

```
#include <ESP8266.h>
```

to this

```
#include <ESP8266_Lib.h>
```

The file was renamed in [this commit](https://github.com/vshymanskyy/BlynkESP8266/commit/c0bb8f3f1ed226e3d297f17a1f55c087c3b4e669#diff-854b02b3217e8797fbf1669e8c78ffc0).

Comment: thanks, this worked. Now I have some new errors, but at least something to play with. Seems like there was an error when I flashed the ESP. Now cant read out the serial port manager in the Arduino IDE =)